# Spring + GWT UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gwt

I looked at almost every topic about org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException but I can't find a solution for my problem. My service looks like this:

```
    @Service
public class PacientService {

    @Resource
    private PacientDAO dao;

    @Resource
    private PacientModelTransformer transformer;

    public PacientService() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public PacientService(PacientDAO dao, PacientModelTransformer transformer) {
        this.dao = dao;
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }

    public PacientDTO getPacientById(Long pacientId) {
        return transformer.toDTO(dao.readByPrimaryKey(pacientId));
    }
}    


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.arprojects.dietetyk" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/d2" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<hades:dao-config base-package="pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.domian" />
```

This is my applicationContext.xml. I really dont know why I've got an exception like this:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pacientService' defined in file [D:\Dietetyk\Dietetyk\target\dietetyk-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\pl\arprojects\dietetyk\server\service\PacientService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.dao.PacientDAO]: : No matching bean of type [pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.dao.PacientDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.dao.PacientDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

No, this DAO hasnt got any subclasses and looks exactly like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PacientDAO extends GenericDao<Pacient, Long> {

     @Query("Select * from dietetyk_pacients where name = :name")
     public Pacient getByName(@Param("name") String name);

     @Query("")
     public void deleteByPrimaryKey(@Param("id") long id);
}
```

Extends GenericDao from Hades Synyx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:hades="http://schemas.synyx.org/hades"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://schemas.synyx.org/hades http://schemas.synyx.org/hades/hades.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/d2" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<hades:dao-config base-package="pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.domian" />
```

applicationContext.xml

Comment: Its clear from the exception that PacientDAO is not loaded in the spring context. As exception says : "No matching bean of type [pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.dao.PacientDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency...".

Comment: I thought that <hades:dao-config base-backage="pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.domian" /> or <context:component-scan base-package="pl.arprojects.dietetyk" /> would do that. If I'm wrong, how should I load DAO to the context?

Comment: Try it <context:component-scan base-package="pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.domian"/>

Comment: Have you used @Autowired for DAOs?

Comment: No I have not. My DAO looks like this:
    <code>@Repository("pacientDAO")
    public interface PacientDAO extends GenericDao<Pacient, Long> {
    
     @Query("Select * from dietetyk_pacients where name = :name")
     public Pacient getByName(@Param("name") String name,      @Param("table") String table);
    
     @Query("")
     public void deleteByPrimaryKey(@Param("id") long pacientId);
    }</code>

Comment: using `<context:component-scan base-package="pl.arprojects.dietetyk.api.domian"/>` also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Repository` or `@Component` annotation for all DAO classes including sub-classes of base DAO and no need to define a name in annotation.

Dependencies are resolved by type.

Comment: I've tried to use `@Repository` or `@Component` annotation on DAO class. Still got UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Comment: Do you have any subclass for this pacientDAO interface and it has annotation? Please share a sample code.

Comment: Then it's clear that there is no class of type PacientDAO. It means exception is OK. Create subclasses so that spring can load them into context and can pass as dependencies for service classes.

Comment: As far as I know, Hades Synyx doesn't require us to create class of type -in this case - PacientDAO, we use just this interface. Am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry I do not have any idea about Hades syntax. I know just about Spring that how it resolves its dependencies. Use GenericDaoFactory in service class to resolve dependencies manually after removing Autowired annotation or use GenericDaoSupport class in place of interface. Sorry I can't help, please read Java Docs about it. Thanks

Comment: I've finally resolved that issue! The problem was in `applicationContext.xml`. When I removed `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, and `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` (According to Hades SYnyx docs those beans suposed to be needed, but...) the problem was resolved.

Comment: When using Hibernate PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor processor is used for exception translation and PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is used to add an advise to any bean that's annotated with @Repository so that platform-specific exception are caught and rethrown as one of Spring's unchecked data access exception. Finally you have resolved it.

Comment: It all was caused because I had no applicationContext dedicated to tests. When I added applicationContext.xml to src/test/resources everything worked fine.